# how to merge 2 ids at once

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I currently have a setup that goes like this:

**Company.rb**

```
 has_many :applications
```

**Application.rb**

```
belongs_to :company
has_many :answers
```

and it stores the company_id when a company creates an application as company_id. 
The company can create questions in the application. Stored as question_1, question_2 and question_3

I then have

**Answers.rb**

```
has_many :users
```

and that contains answer_1, answer_2, answer_3 and stores the user_id to who answered it.

I have set up the controller in **Answers** so that I view the applications in

```
answers#show
```

with the routing:

```
match '/answers/:id', to: 'answers#show', via: 'get'
```

so when I visit /answers/5 I get that the application belongs_to company with user_id 1 and the application belongs to the application with id of 10. For example.
I get that by showing in the **answers/show.html.erb**:

```
<%= @application.company_id %>
<%= @application.id %>
```

now I've created a form in the show that looks like this:

```
<%= form_for @answer do |f| %>
  <p>Question 1: <%= @application.question_1 %></p>
  <%= f.text_area :answer_1 %><br/>

  <p>Question 2: <%= @application.question_2 %></p>
  <%= f.text_area :answer_2 %><br/>

  <p>Question 3: <%= @application.question_3 %></p>
  <%= f.text_area :answer_3 %>

  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

and the **answers_controller.rb** looks like this:

```
class AnswersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def new
    @answer = Answer.new
  end

  def show
    @application = Application.find(params[:id])
    @answer = Answer.new
  end 


  def create
    @answer = Answer.new(answer_params.merge(:user_id => current_user.id))
    if @answer.save
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  private

  def answer_params
    params.require(:answer).permit(:answer_1, :answer_2, :answer_3)
  end
end
```

so when I answer a question it stores it like this in the database:

[image: http://s1.postimg.org/qsl2e5wj3/Screen_Shot_2014_06_23_at_14_02_06.png]

and when I create an application it stores it like this in the database:

[image: http://s11.postimg.org/ia1snyh4z/Screen_Shot_2014_06_23_at_14_02_58.png]

What I want now is that the answers are connected with the application_id. I am not sure how to do a double merge as I already take user_id from current_user.id.

The end goal is for the Company to be able to view the users and what they answered to their application.

So how do I add it so that I can save both the current_user.id and the application_id those answers belongs to. I know there must be some easy way as my routing already shows the application you are answering. But not sure how to add that to the database (controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways those come to my mind to implement such thing:

1. Add the `application_id` in a hidden field so it will automatically be available while saving the answer.
2. Change the routes for create action to nest into the application. ie. `application/:application_id/answers/:id`.

To implement the first, you just need to add a hidden field like:

```
<%= form_for @answer do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :application_id, value: @application.id %>
  <p>Question 1: <%= @application.question_1 %></p>
  <%= f.text_area :answer_1 %><br/>
  # omitted code.
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

For the implementation of the latter method, you can nest your create action of answers controller under application resources. in routes.rb:

```
resources :applications do # I am not sure how have you set up routes but if you're using resources than use it.
  resources :answers, only: [:create]
end
```

Now, in your answers/show.html.erb replace form declaration with:

```
<%= form_for [@application, @answer] do |f| %>
```

Finally, you can access your application id in create action as:

```
def create
  @application = Application.find(params[:application_id])
  @answer = @application.answers.new(answer_params.merge(:user_id => current_user.id))
  if @answer.save
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

Comment: I decided to go with the first. It worked perfectly and it was stupidly obvious when you point it out :)! Thanks Manoj